# Loop through multiple lists simultaneously?

Tags: python, loops

I am looking for some help with loops. I have a name list, and I'm looking to sequentially message each profile from that list with a random user inputted message.

Ideally this would involve looping through the profileLink items while simultaneously looping through the nameList items so that I can build a new messageInput for each profile.

My code works, but currently has a lot of duplication and to build this to support a larger list will involve a lot of copying and pasting, as you can see below - How would you go about this?

```
messageInput0="Hi " + f'{namelist[0]}' + ", " + f'{choice(messageOptions)}'
messageInput1="Hi " + f'{namelist[1]}' + ", " + f'{choice(messageOptions)}'
messageInput2="Hi " + f'{namelist[2]}' + ", " + f'{choice(messageOptions)}'
messageInput3="Hi " + f'{namelist[3]}' + ", " + f'{choice(messageOptions)}'
messageInput4="Hi " + f'{namelist[4]}' + ", " + f'{choice(messageOptions)}'

webbrowser.open(profileLink[0])
time.sleep(6)
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write(messageInput0, interval=random.uniform(0.03, 0.15))

with pyautogui.hold('command'):
    pyautogui.press('w')

webbrowser.open(profileLink[1])
time.sleep(6)
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write(messageInput1, interval=random.uniform(0.03, 0.15))

with pyautogui.hold('command'):
    pyautogui.press('w')

webbrowser.open(profileLink[2])
time.sleep(6)
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write(messageInput2, interval=random.uniform(0.03, 0.15))

with pyautogui.hold('command'):
    pyautogui.press('w')

    webbrowser.open(profileLink[3])
time.sleep(6)
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write(messageInput3, interval=random.uniform(0.03, 0.15))

with pyautogui.hold('command'):
    pyautogui.press('w')

    webbrowser.open(profileLink[4])
time.sleep(6)
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write(messageInput4, interval=random.uniform(0.03, 0.15))

with pyautogui.hold('command'):
    pyautogui.press('w')
```

EDIT: After trying the top answer, I got the error that list object has no attribute 'replace'

Worth mentioning my list is built using str.replace/str.split functions, like so:

```
profileLink = open("profiles.txt").read().splitlines()

profileLink = [item.replace("+","name=") for item in profileLink]
newLinks = [item.replace("%","name=") for item in profileLink]
nameList = [i.split("name=")[1] for i in newLinks]
```

EDIT 2: First edit was actually an unrelated error. Fixed now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-do-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so.

- Use `zip` to "zip up" the name and profile link and you don't have to keep track of loop indexes.

```
import random
import time
import pyautogui
import webbrowser

namelist = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
profilelink = ["q", "w", "e", "r"]
messageOptions = ["bye", "hello"]

for name, link in zip(namelist, profilelink):
    message = f"Hi {name}, {random.choice(messageOptions)}"

    webbrowser.open(link)
    time.sleep(6)
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.write(message, interval=random.uniform(0.03, 0.15))

    with pyautogui.hold("command"):
        pyautogui.press("w")
```

Comment: This almost got me there, some added context:
I am creating the profileLink list and nameList with split and replace operations

`profileLink = open("profiles.txt").read().splitlines()


profileLink = [item.replace("+","name=") for item in profileLink]
newLinks = [item.replace("%","name=") for item in profileLink]
nameList = [i.split("name=")[1] for i in newLinks]
`

As a result when I run this code, I am getting an error that the list object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I've tried formatting as a string literal but it seems the webbrowser command won't work on a string literal?

Comment: That error is unrelated to this code, and as far as I can see there's nothing there that could throw that error.

Comment: You are correct. This is solved now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it:

```
import random
import time
import webbrowser


def messageInput(nameList, profileLink):
    for name in nameList:
        message = "Hi " + f'{name}' + ", " + f'{choice(messageOptions)}'
        for profile in profileLink:
            webbrowser.open(profile)
            time.sleep(6)
            pyautogui.press('tab')
            pyautogui.write(message, interval=random.uniform(0.03, 0.15))

        with pyautogui.hold('command'):
            pyautogui.press('w')
```

Comment: I've tried this and the browser doesn't launch - could be to do with how I've built the list? (see my recent edit)

Comment: Could you give me an example of how your data looks inside profilelink ? just random data so that i see how it looks

Comment: I tried the top comment again and seemed to get it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: But the data was just URLs, each on a new line :)'

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(profileLink)):
    webbrowser.open(profileLink[i])
    time.sleep(6)
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    message = f'Hi {namelist[i]}, {choice(messageOptions)}'
    pyautogui.write(message, interval=random.uniform(0.03, 0.15))
```

Comment: Using `for i in range(len(...))` is not quite Pythonic...

Comment: @AKX What makes it... non-pythonic?

Comment: The Pythonic way to iterate over a single iterable with indices, you'd use `for i, x in enumerate(l)`, but since you're only using `i` to be able to index into the other "parallel" list you don't need it at all; you'd use `for x, y in zip()` to iterate them in in parallel.

Comment: @AKX `zip()` is obviously a better solution here, but I wasn't aware iterating over `range(len(...))` (vs directly over `enumerate(...)`) was considered an antipattern, thanks!

Comment: One more data point (that's not relevant in _this_ case): `range(len())` won't work if you can't know the length of iterable, and considering [There should be one obvious way to do it.
](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) using a different pattern for lengthable iterables vs. others seems non-Pythonic :)